# How to mark a specific x value on x-axis without using ggplot?

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot of a quadratic function using the following R code.
I wonder if there's a way to mark the value of axis of symmetry on the x-axis (which is the value of vertical line).

```
b1 = 2
b2 = -1
c =100

x = -10:10
f <- function(x) {
return(c + b1 * x + b2 * x^2) 
}

plot(x, f(x))

abline(v =-b1/(2*b2), col = "red", lwd = 1, lty = 1)
```

Comment: `axis(1, 1, "1")`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `mtext` with `as.character` to get the value like this:

```r
b1 = 2
b2 = -1
c =100

x = -10:10
f <- function(x) {
  return(c + b1 * x + b2 * x^2) 
}

plot(x, f(x))
abline(v =-b1/(2*b2), col = "red", lwd = 1, lty = 1)
mtext(as.character(-b1/(2*b2)),1,line=1,at=-b1/(2*b2),col="red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>